Markov kernels as measurable functions
Based on the wikipedia definition, we have the following for `measurable' functions:
Let $(X,\mathcal{A})$ and $(Z,\mathcal{C})$ be measurable spaces then a function $f:X \to Z$ is measurable if $f^{-1}(E) = \{x \in X|f(x) \in E\} \in \mathcal{A}$ for every $E \in \mathcal{C}$.
So, to comment if a function is measurable, we need to know the $\sigma$-algebras of both the domain and the range. Now, the following is the Wikipedia definition for a Markov kernel.
Let $(X,\mathcal{A})$ and $(Y,\mathcal{B})$ be measurable spaces. In the definition of Markov kernel $K:X\times\mathcal{B}\rightarrow[0,1]$, it is required that

$K(x,\cdot)$ is a probability measure on $(Y,\mathcal{B})$ for all $x\in X$.
$K(\cdot,B)$ is $\mathcal{A}$-measurable for all $B\in\mathcal{B}$.

My question is regarding (2). Fix any $B \in \mathcal{B}$. $K(\cdot,B)$ maps $X$ to $[0,1]$. How do we comment on measurability of this map without defining a $\sigma$-algebra for $[0,1]$? I suppose one could just choose the Borel $\sigma$-algebra as a default choice but as I understand it, there could be different algebras as well.
I do not know measure theory so I apologize if this is something trivial!

When the definition is stated like that, it refers to the Borel $\sigma$-algebra in $\mathbb{R}$. In general, unless otherwise stated, the $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}^d$ in probability theory is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra with respect to the Euclidean topology.
